# 100% kernel load on FreeBSD 9

Tags: freebsd, cpu-usage

I'm having problems with a FreeBSD 9 server. One of the 8 cores (4 w/ HT) is constantly at 100% kernel load.

`top` gives me:

```
CPU:  0.0% user,  0.0% nice, 12.5% system,  0.0% interrupt, 87.5% idle
```

Notice that 12.5% is exactly 100%/8.

`top -S` shows me that geom is the problem:

```
13 root        3  -8    -     0K    48K -       7 385.2H 100.00% geom
```

I checked with iostat if there's something IO-heavy going on, but the server is currently idle:

```
pascal@srv ~$ iostat 1 5  
       tty            ada0             ada1            pass1             cpu
 tin  tout  KB/t tps  MB/s   KB/t tps  MB/s   KB/t tps  MB/s  us ni sy in id
   0     6 22.07   6  0.13  22.43   9  0.20   0.00   0  0.00   0  0  4  0 96
   0   234  0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0  0 13  0 87
   0    78  0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0  0 12  0 87
   0    78  0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0  0 13  0 87
   0    78  0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0.00   0  0.00   0  0 12  0 88
```

There's also plenty of free RAM

```
Mem: 1174M Active, 4399M Inact, 8241M Wired, 208M Cache, 1726M Free
```

There's no swap configured, but I noticed some strange errors in dmesg.today

```
swap_pager: I/O error - pagein failed; blkno 288,size 12288, error 6
vm_fault: pager read error, pid 95209 (nginx)
```

There are about 30 of these per day. I added a swap file but they persist. I also stopped nginx, but the load doesn't go down.

Where can I find more information on why geom is using so much CPU? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a swap file before? It looks like it's constantly virtual memory page faulting, but you obviously have free memory. Strange.

Comment: No, I haven't had a swap file before. The server has 16GB of RAM and roughly 1.5GB is used. Also, after I added the swap file, these errors kept appearing. `Swap: 4160M Total, 836K Used, 4159M Free`

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment here as this is no real answer. The problem was a broken harddrive. 15 hours after I asked this question ada0 simply disappeared in /dev. The hdd was replaced, I rebooted and the load is gone.

Comment: oh, awesome. So it was constantly rebuilding or something. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this was really this issue in FreeBSD,

[Bug 171865](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=171865)

You resolved it by rebooting.

Comment: Thanks. The bug report also shows how the reporter found the cause of the high load: `sudo dtrace -n 'fbt:kernel:g_*:entry { @[probefunc, stack()] = count(); } tick-1sec { trunc(@, 3); printa(@); `